# Get access to static member from array/list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, static

Situation:

```
ClassA
{
     static string c;
}

 ClassB
 {
     public List<ClassA> Collection;
}

....

ClassB b;
```

How can I get access to a `static` member of `ClassA` having object `b` of `ClassB`? Here it is `string c`.

Comment: Why not just ClassA.c?

Comment: Static members don't _belong_ to an instance but to the class. [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx): _"Members of a class are either static members or instance members. Generally speaking, it is useful to think of static members as belonging to classes and instance members as belonging to objects (instances of classes)."_

Comment: Simple answer .. you can't since it's a static member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get static members from a class instance (so you can't do `b.Collection[0].c`).

You do have the ability to use reflection to get the type member, but that wouldn't be the best option in my opinion.

I think you'd better create a non-static accessor for the static member:

```
public string C
{
    get
    {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that at all? The static member does not belong to the instance, `c` is the same for all instances of `ClassA` in `Collection`.

Comment: Well, some times you have something that is static, since you want to share it across instances, but you also want to access it from an instance that is passed around.

Comment: But you _can_ access it via class, you don't need the instance (and you can't use it from an instance anyway).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Sorry, I think I understand you better now. `c` belongs to `ClassA` instead of `ClassB`, you are right.

Comment: Yes correct but that's not the suggested way to access a static member. Why would someone at all want to access a static member from a instance variable???

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I updated the `b.c` to be more correct. Any more suggestions?